# Change which NuGet packages are installed by default

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013, nuget, nuget-package

When creating a new project in Visual Studio, say an MVC web app, several NuGet packages are installed by default (Antlr, Modernizr, WebGrease, etc.).

I would like to change the NuGet packages which are installed by default.  For example, I may want to remove Antlr from the default list and add EntityFramework.

Is this possible?  If so, how can I achieve this?